# logrotate :: How to delete old logs in a logfile after logfile size reaches 1M size

Tags: logrotate

How can I keep log file size limited to 1M?
I want to delete old log entries in a log file after log file size reaches 1M size. I do not want to delete the log file itself.

Comment: Can you add a little more explanation to your question, show us your logrotate configuration file,

Comment: Of course, logrotate is not always a pre-requisite: http://askubuntu.com/a/623101/43344

Answer (score -2):

Here's one way.

```
[root@localhost tmp]# ls -lh log.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 601M Jun 30 15:21 log.txt
[root@localhost tmp]# tail --bytes=1048576 log.txt >log.txt.tmp
[root@localhost tmp]# mv log.txt.tmp log.txt
[root@localhost tmp]# ls -lh log.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.0M Jul  1 01:35 log.txt
[root@localhost tmp]#
```